# Image cover the background color of div

Tags: css

Image cover the background color of DIV but text is showing.

My code is

```
<div id="testing">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/1413142095961484763cf/d141726c?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1350&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
  <div id="sample">
  Text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS is

```
#testing {
  width: 200px;
  height:150px;
}
img {
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
}
#sample {
  margin-top:-15px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

The result is showing like

[image]

You can find the code at

https://jsfiddle.net/cz605rc5/

It can solve with background css for div.

But I prefer to use img and **want to cover black background label at the bottom of the image.**

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you give us a better idea of your issue and what you want the end result to be?

Comment: @andrewgu , you can see at the end of questions, "want to cover black background label at the bottom of the image"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a transparento overlay over your image tag since, it will be transparent the image will act as a background..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/q1m3zbwz/)

```
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Then you can move the text inside the overlay as you wish..

Answer (score 1):

Since we are in 2017 i think you should first change the HTML code:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption><span lang="en">image title</span></figcaption>
  <img src="img.png" alt="Alternative Text" / >
</figure>
```

Now for CSS:
All you need is to make figcaption size as the image size. 
Then make it position absolute, change it's z-index higher than the img, and set it's background to gradient. 
Last thing is to place the span in some place: set it's position to "absolute" and place it (for example: left: 5px; bottom: 15px;)

If you want the full css just ask (:

Answer (score 0):

Line height is causing the issue.  You can add a `line-height: 0;` to #sample, or you can change the line height of the body.  You could even enclose the text in some tags and apply it to that.